# Detect if App is launched from Add to Home icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad, detect

I am using [Cubic](http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen) to implement `'Add to home'` functionality. What I want to know is how can I detect if my application is launched from the icon created by 'add to home' or from any browser.

I want this check basically on iPad. Usually there are 3 ways my users access my app on iPad:

1. Shortcut on home (created by add to home)
2. Google Chrome
3. Safari

I could detect the 2nd and 3rd. But I couldn't detect the 1st one.

This is how I check if the user is using iPad:

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
if(isiPad){
  /* do something */
}
```

This is how I check if the user is using Google Chrome on iPad:

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match('CriOS')){
  /* do something */
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: if you know how to detect 2nd and 3nd. So when it is not the 2nd & 3rd case then it will from 'Add to Home' button.

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar but if it is not 2nd and 3rd it can be any other browser from desktop too. I am looking for iPad basically.

Comment: Please share some code what have you tried.